# How to get instagram Stories Highlights using c#?

Tags: c#, instagram-api, instagram-story

I'm writing app using c#, I use InstaSharper library. I want to get user "Stories Highlights", but there are only method `GetUserStoryFeedAsync()` to get current user stories. How can I get user "Stories Highlights"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = await InstaApi.UserProcessor.GetUserAsync("giorgos.xou");
var userId = user.Value.Pk.ToString();
var Highlights = await InstaApi.StoryProcessor.GetHighlightFeedsAsync(userId);

foreach (InstaHighlightFeed Highlight in Highlights.Value.Items)
{
    //sb2.AppendLine(Highlight.Title);
}
```